# What does a number mean before a for-loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python. Would greatly appreciate if you could explain how this line works. What does it mean to have a number before a for-loop?

```
adjacency_matrix = [[0 for i in range(max_index + 1)] for j in range(max_index + 1)]
```

I know that

```
max_index = 4
adjacency_matrix = [[0 for i in range(max_index + 1)] for j in range(max_index + 1)]
>>>[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But I don't understand how it works.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to select an answer (the checkmark) and vote for useful answers and comments.

Comment: Side-note: `[[0] * (max_index+1) for i in range(max_index + 1)]` is a slightly more efficient way to do this. You can't make the outer wrapping by multiplication (because it duplicates the contained references, rather than making copies), but since the innermost list contains immutable types, it can be formed by sequence multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You can rewrite that as follows:

```
>>> adjacency_matrix = []
>>> for j in range(max_index + 1):
...     inner_list = []
...     for i in range(max_index + 1):
...         inner_list.append(0)
...     adjacency_matrix.append(inner_list)
```

Comment: I see it now. Thanks a lot. 
I found a good video that explained step by step
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dt4OGnU5sM

Answer (score 1):

If we use variable in list comprehension to populate a list, the resultant list takes the value of the variable whenever condition met. Since we are using '0' means list get populated by the value '0' whenever condition met.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` is the value which the list comprehension is adding to the array (list) - same way each list of zeros is getting nested in the parent list. Try changing it to a different integer, float, string, boolean, etc...

```
>>> max_index = 4
>>> adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix = [[True for i in range(max_index + 1)] for j in range(max_index + 1)]
>>> adjacency_matrix
[[True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True]]
```

Otherwise, see @ozgur's answer for a translation of the list comprehension into articulated for-loops and a link to the PyDoc for list comps.

Essentially, tho, what you are invoking is:

```
[ ADD_THE_FOLLOWING_LISTS:

  [ADD_THIS_VALUE_TO_EACH_INNER_LIST = 0, True, etc...
   `for` each_integer
   `in` the `range`_of
   (zero through four - not including five)]  = [value, value, value, value, value]

...............................`for` each_number
                               `in` the `range`_of
                               (zero through four - not including five)]  
    ]   =  a (4 + 1) x (4 + 1), or 5x5 grid of values

[ [value, value, value, value, value],
  [value, value, value, value, value],
  [value, value, value, value, value],
  [value, value, value, value, value],
  [value, value, value, value, value] ]
```